# Android - catch the "Cancel" event when installing an .apk programmatically

Tags: android, installation, apk

[this is the situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tz1uM.png)

After downloaded an apk file, I use the following code to start installation, it works well.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String action = intent.getAction();

    if (action.equals(BroadcastActionConstants.DOWNLOAD_FINISHED)) {
        // download finished
        final File file = (File) intent.getExtras()
                .getSerializable(DownloadService.DOWNLOAD_FILE);

        Intent install = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        String pathString = file.getAbsolutePath();
        install.setDataAndType(
                Uri.fromFile(new File(pathString)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
        install.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(install);
    }
}
```

Now I want to catch the "Cancel" event when the installation page prompt up. plz help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add another Receiver to listen for the installed package

```
<receiver android:name=".ApkInstalledReceiver" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
        <data android:scheme="package" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

so, if the user cancels the installation you won't receive it.

Comment: you are not answering my question....what if I want to delete the apk file if user clicked the "Cancel" button? Have you seen the screen shot? here's the link [link] (http://i.stack.imgur.com/Tz1uM.png) plz check

Comment: If not installed therefore it was canceled

Comment: thank you, i make a detour and avoid this problem :)

Comment: @ChinglimCHAN now how you get this cancel event?